# database design for large number of users

Tags: database

which one is better a or b:
a). 7 tables for each user e.g. user7 messages, user7mail etc.In this case if we have 1000 users the there will be 7000 tables.

b). 7 tables e.g. messages, mails etc. all the messasges or mails of every usr will be on same table.
in this case for 1000 users we have only 7 tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases, on modern hardware and with reasonable tuning, your database should be able to support tens of millions of records without too much pain, as long as your data really is relational. If you're searching for text, or storing hierarchical data, or storing documents, or running reports, there are alternative options (e.g. NoSQL).

Where at all possible, stick with the orthodox way of using relational databases; that means [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), [query tuning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_tuning), using caches and throwing hardware at the problem.

Only once you've proven you have a performance problem is it worth looking at more exotic solutions. Within RDBMS world, that might mean [partitioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28database%29) the data (sorta kinda similar to your "table per user" idea). Alternatively, you might jump to NoSQL.

The problems with your "table per user" strategy is that you gain almost no benefit when querying by index (on a modern RDBMS, searching a table with 1 row or a table with million rows when hitting the index makes almost no difference for finding the data). For actions that don't hit the index, you should see a decent gain - but that's usually a sign you're not really relational in the first place...

It makes developing the client application rather error prone, and more complicated than it needs to be, especially when creating moderately complex SQL queries (e.g. multi-table joins) - and tuning those queries will become much harder as a result. You won't be able to use the tools available to manage database queries (e.g. ORM tools), as these are all based on the "standard" relational model.

The biggest problem is changing the database - if you have to add an attribute to "message", you have to repeat that change over 7000 tables. You'll either spend a lot of time writing custom database management scripts, or have a human being repeat the same thing thousands of times (and make hard-to-spot mistakes).

Answer (score 0):

Case B will be much better, just make sure that your users have a user_id type field that increments automatically, and link your tables together via that ID e.g.

```
user_id email
1000     hello
```

This will improve lookup speed because you do not have to iclude functionality to choose a specific piece of data from a search of 1000's of tables (in this case it would be searching columns of tables until it found the right table with the right column, it would be ludicrous)

but if you are searching a specific table (e.g. you only need messages) only 1 table will be included in the lookup, much faster and easier to manage all the tables at an admin level.

but and even better idea would be 1 table with several columns, say a 'communications' table which could be like

```
user_id  email   messages
1000     hello   hi
```

Comment: thanks seanyt123
can you explain about a database structure of a management system with more than 50000 users

Comment: Well it solely depends on what different data you want to store.